# I am getting segmentation fault in this assembly code "nasm"

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I wrote this assembly code but I am getting segmentation fault.

My code shows if a year had one day more or not, so instead of a regular 365 days, it has 366 days. This happens in years that are divisible by 4 but not 100, or divisible by 100 and 400. So 2008 it is because divides 4 but not 100, 2000 it is because divides 100 and 400, but 2200 is not because divides 100 but not 400.

I tried to debug and the segmentation happens in my if statement when div100 is call, it does the division but in the return line the segmentation happen.

Not sure why this is happening. Please help.

Enter a year: [2008 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**CODE:**

```
extern printf, scanf  

global _start

section .data

format db '%d',0  
message: db " %d is a leap year.",10,0 ;    
message2: db " %d is not a leap year",10,0 ;  

message3: db "Enter a year: ",10,0

len1: equ $ - message
len2: equ $ - message2
len3: equ $ - message3

divisor1:   dq 4
divisor2: dq 100
divisor3:   dq 400
  
section .bss
year:   resq 1

section .text


_start:
   call _intro ;asking to enter year

scan:  ;getting the year

mov rdi, format

mov rsi, year   

mov rax, 0

call scanf


if:  ;the case the year is divisble by 4 but not 100

   call _div4

   cmp rdx,0

   jne elseIf

   je _div100 ;

   cmp rdx,0

   je elseIf

   jne _isLeapYear

   jmp exit


elseIf: ;case the year is divisible by 100 and 400

   call _div100

   cmp rdx, 0

   jne else

   je _div400

   cmp rdx, 0

   jne else

   je _isLeapYear

   jmp exit


else: ;the case that all the other cases failed 

   call _isNotLeapYear

  
  
exit:  ;ending program

   mov rax,60 ;

xor rdi, rdi ;

syscall ;


;functions

_div4:

mov rax, [year]

mov rdx, 0

idiv qword[divisor1]

   ret


_div100:

mov rax, [year]

mov rdx, 0

idiv qword[divisor2]

ret ; I think segmentation is happening right here !!!


_div400:

mov rax, [year]

mov rdx, 0

   idiv qword[divisor3]

   ret

  
_isLeapYear:

   mov rax,0

   mov rdi, message

   mov rsi,[year]

   call printf

   jmp exit


_isNotLeapYear:

mov rax,0

mov rdi, message2

mov rsi,[year]

call printf

   jmp exit


_intro:

mov rax,1 ; 
  
mov rdi,1 ;  
 
mov rsi, message3 ;

   mov rdx,len3 ;   

syscall ;

ret
```

Comment: `je _div100` but then you `ret` from `_div100`, trying to return to a return address on the stack that isn't there.

Comment: I do not understand, how can I fix this then? I thought I needed to return because is a function, I just want to divide by 100 and make sure that the remaining is zero.

Comment: Yes, it's a function, so you need to call it with `call`, not with a jump that doesn't push a return address.  To do that conditionally, you'll need to conditionally jump past the `call`.

Comment: @NateEldredge is correct.  ```ret``` returns to the address that's (assumedly) at the top of stack, saved by the ```call``` instruction you (assumedly) entered the function with.  ```je``` saves no such pointer and ```ret``` is trying to return to whatever's there instead.  Apparently, it is not a valid address to jump to.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you so much for your explanation. I understand now.